# Including onclick action in href

Tags: woocommerce, setattribute, product-variations

I have a woocommerce webshop where i try to include an setAttribute('open', 'true') to a variation label.

However, it gives an error when returning the label: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'open' (T_STRING) in .../shortcode.php on line 95

I changed the quotes for double quotes and vice versa but doesnt solve it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label' , 'modify_the_attribute_filter' , 10 , 3 );

function modify_the_attribute_filter( $label , $name , $product ){
$id = get_the_id();

if ( ($id ==189 || $id == 32 || $id == 754) && !is_admin() ){

if( $label == 'Lunch' ){
    $label .= '<a class="extra_label" href="#anchor" onclick="det.setAttribute('open', 'true'); return false;">i</a>';
}
else {
    $label .= '<a class="extra_label" href="#anchor">i</a>';
}
} 
return $label;
 }
```

The goal is that every variation label contains a clickable item that is an anchor to a point on the page and at the same time opens a details-summary box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to escape the quotes as following ?

```
$label .= '<a class="extra_label" href="#anchor" onclick="det.setAttribute(\'open\', \'true\'); return false;">i</a>';
```

Comment: Although there is no error, nothing is passed in the url. I think there is some sanitization in this filter...